# jQuery Not Working in Express JS - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Ok, so I'm new to Express. I'm messing around with sessions and ajax calls, but the problem I'm having is that whenever I run my app, my jquery doesn't work for some reason.  This is the code I have:

**app.js**

```
var express    = require("express");
var mongoose   = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var session    = require('express-session')

var app = express();
app.use(express.static("public")); // I understand this is the directory where I would need to put all my static files: css, js, images, etc.
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//Set secre pass for the session
app.use(session({secret:'password'}));


app.get("/",function(req, res){

    if(req.session.userName){
        res.render("admin", {session_name: req.session.userName});
    }else{
        res.render("home");
    }

});

app.post("/example-ajax", function(req, res){
    res.send(req.body.email); // return the email that was sent by the client
});

app.post("/log-in", function(req, res){
    req.session.userName = req.body.name;
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/log-out", function(req, res){
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(8080);
```

**admin.jade**

```
extends layout_head.jade
block content
    div(class="container")
        div(class="row")
            div(class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3")
                h1 Logged In!!
                h3 Logged in as: #[b #{session_name}]
                a(href="/log-out") Log Out
                br
                div(class="btn btn-info testAjax") Test Ajax

    script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js")
    script(href="/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")
    script(href="/js/main.js")
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Loaded");

    $(".testAjax").on("click", function(){
        alert("test");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/example-ajax',
            data: {
                email: "admin@yahoo.com"
            },
            success: function(data){
                // data = the email being returned from the server
                console.log("Your email is: " + data);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

So like I said, the jquery doesn't run whenever my page loads up or when I click the testAjax button. When I check the console, it doesn't give me any errors so I don't know what is causing the problem.

My second question is: Is this the right way to make ajax calls in Express?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: script src and script href? looks like jquery loaded, but not other scripts

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Haha WOW I can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks for your comment. It's working now. You should write the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to change href to src in the script tags.